# How to store result set of a SQL Statement into a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SP and I want to know if I can store a result of a statement into a variable upon which I will trigger another query.

For instance, below query gives me an `id` and I need to use this `id` for another Insert statement.

```
variable id = Select id from tableA where myCondition = 'this';
Insert into tableB values(id, a, ab ,c);
```

I am not sure if something exists like this in SQL Server where I can define a variable in this case `id` is of type int and user it later.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply declare a variable and assign the result of the query to the variable.

```
DECLARE @Id INT = (SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE myCondition = 'this');
```

then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO tableB values(@Id, a, ab ,c);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 1 row returned in your select statement then you can use a table variable:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (id int) 

INSERT INTO @temp (id)
SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE myCondition = 'this'

INSERT INTO tableB
SELECT T.id, a, ab, c
  FROM @temp T  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Zorkolot. It's nice to know this as well. :)